# Redux store not being populated when mocking API call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, redux, msw

I wrote a Register component in react, it is a simple form that on submit will post to an API. The call to the API will return an object with certain data, this data will be then added to the redux store.

I wrote some tests for this. I'm using Mock Service Worker (MSW) to mock the API call. This is my first time for writing these kind of tests so I'm not sure if I'm doing anything wrong, but my understanding was that MSW would intercept the call to the API and return whatever I specify in the MSW config, after that it should follow the regular flow.

Here's my reducer:

```
const authReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {

        case actionTypes.REGISTER_NEW_USER:
            const newUser = new User().register(
                action.payload.email,
                action.payload.firstName,
                action.payload.lastName,
                action.payload.password
            )
            console.log("User registered data back:");
            console.log(newUser);
            return {
                ...state,
                'user': newUser
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

this is my User class where the actual call is performed:

```
import axios from "axios";
import { REGISTER_API_ENDPOINT } from "../../api";

export default class User {

    /**
     * Creates a new user in the system
     *
     * @param {string} email - user's email address
     * @param {string} firstName - user's first name
     * @param {string} lastName - user's last name
     * @param {string} password - user's email address
     */
    register(email, firstName, lastName, password) {
        // console.log("registering...")
        axios.post(REGISTER_API_ENDPOINT, {
            email,
            firstName,
            lastName,
            password
        })
            .then(function (response) {
                return {
                    'email': response.data.email,
                    'token': response.data.token,
                    'active': response.data.active,
                    'loggedIn': response.data.loggedIn,
                }
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log('error');
                console.log(error);
            });
    }
}
```

this is my action creator:

```
export function createNewUser(userData) {
    return {
        type: REGISTER_NEW_USER,
        payload: userData
    }
}
```

this is the `onSubmit` method in my Register component:

```
const onSubmit = data => {
        // console.log(data);
        if (data.password !== data.confirmPassword) {
            console.log("Invalid password")
            setError('password', {
                type: "password",
                message: "Passwords don't match"
            })
            return;
        }

        // if we got up to this point we don't need to submit the password confirmation
        // todo but we might wanna pass it all the way through to the backend TBD
        delete data.confirmPassword

        dispatch(createNewUser(data))
    }
```

and this is my actual test:

```
describe('Register page functionality', () => {

    const server = setupServer(
        rest.post(REGISTER_API_ENDPOINT, (req, res, ctx) => {
            console.log("HERE in mock server call")
            // Respond with a mocked user object
            return res(
                ctx.status(200),
                ctx.json({
                'email': faker.internet.email(),
                'token': faker.datatype.uuid(),
                'active': true,
                'loggedIn': true,
            }))
        })
    )

    // Enable API mocking before tests
    beforeEach(() => server.listen());

    // Reset any runtime request handlers we may add during the tests.
    afterEach(() => server.resetHandlers())

    // Disable API mocking after the tests are done.
    afterAll(() => server.close())


    it('should perform an api call for successful registration', async () => {

        // generate random data to be used in the form
        const email = faker.internet.email();
        const firstName = faker.name.firstName();
        const lastName = faker.name.lastName();
        const password = faker.internet.password();

        // Render the form
        const { store } = renderWithRedux(<Register />);

        // Add values to the required input fields
        const emailInput = screen.getByTestId('email-input')
        userEvent.type(emailInput, email);

        const firstNameInput = screen.getByTestId('first-name-input');
        userEvent.type(firstNameInput, firstName);

        const lastNameInput = screen.getByTestId('last-name-input');
        userEvent.type(lastNameInput, lastName);

        const passwordInput = screen.getByTestId('password-input');
        userEvent.type(passwordInput, password);
        const confirmPasswordInput = screen.getByTestId('confirm-password-input');
        userEvent.type(confirmPasswordInput, password);

        // Click on the Submit button
        await act(async () => {
            userEvent.click(screen.getByTestId('register-submit-button'));

            // verify the store was populated
            console.log(await store.getState())
        });
    });
```

So I was expecting my call to be intercepted whenever the REGISTER_API_ENDPOINT url is detected, and the value of the mocked call to be added to my redux state instead of the value of the actual API call in `register` method but that doesn't seem to be happening. If that's not the way to test a value in the store, how else can I achieve that?

So at the end of my test, when printing the store I was expecting to see:

```
{ auth: { user:
{
                'email': faker.internet.email(),
                'token': faker.datatype.uuid(),
                'active': true,
                'loggedIn': true,
            }
}
```

but instead I'm seeing:

```
 { auth: { user: null } }
```

Is this the right approach for this test?

Thanks

---

**EDIT**

Doing some refactoring based on the comments. Now my `onSubmit` method looks like:

```
const onSubmit = async data => {

        if (data.password !== data.confirmPassword) {
            console.log("Invalid password")
            setError('password', {
                type: "password",
                message: "Passwords don't match"
            })
            return;
        }

        // if we got up to this point we don't need to submit the password confirmation
        // todo but we might wanna pass it all the way through to the backend TBD
        delete data.confirmPassword

        let user = new User()
        await user.register(data).
        then(
            data => {
                // console.log("Response:")
                // console.log(data)
                // create cookies
                cookie.set("user", data.email);
                cookie.set("token", data.token);
                dispatch(createNewUser(data))
            }
        ).catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Notice that now I'm dispatching the response from `User.register` in here instead of doing it in `User.register`. Also notice that this function is now `async` and `await` for the `register` function call to be finalized, at that moment it'll populate the store.

The `register` method now looks like the following:

```
async register(data) {

        let res = await axios.post(REGISTER_API_ENDPOINT, {
             'email': data.email,
             'firstName': data.firstName,
             'lastName': data.lastName,
             'password': data.password
        })
            .then(function (response) {
                return response
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log('error');
                console.log(error);
            });

        return await res.data;
    }
```

now it's only in charge of performing the API call and returning the response.

The reducer was also simplified not to have any side effect changes, so it looks like:

```
const authReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {

        case actionTypes.REGISTER_NEW_USER:
            const newUser = action.payload
            return {
                ...state,
                'user': newUser
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

my test is mostly the same, the only difference is the part where I'm inspecting the `store` value:

```
// Click on the Submit button
        await act(async () => {
            userEvent.click(screen.getByTestId('register-submit-button'));
        });

        await waitFor(() => {
            // verify the store was populated
            console.log("Store:")
            console.log(store.getState())
        })
```

Now, this sometimes work and sometimes does not. Meaning, sometimes I get correct store printed as follows:

```
 console.log
      Store:

      at test/pages/Register.test.js:219:21

    console.log
      {
        auth: {
          user: {
            email: 'Selena.Tremblay@hotmail.com',
            token: '1a0fadc7-7c13-433b-b86d-368b4e2311eb',
            active: true,
            loggedIn: true
          }
        }
      }

      at test/pages/Register.test.js:220:21
```

but sometimes I'm getting `null`:

```
 console.log
      Store:

      at test/pages/Register.test.js:219:21

    console.log
      { auth: { user: null } }

      at test/pages/Register.test.js:220:21
```

I guess I'm missing some async code somewhere but I cannot put a pin on where is it.

Comment: When you run yor appliction normally in the brower, does this line `console.log(newUser);` logs `newUser` with right values? it seems you aren't returning anything from `register` method in the `user` class.

Comment: @MrCujo you are not awaiting the xcompletion of the onSubmit handler correctly. Maybe try awaiting a delay of some 200ms as per answer by gunwin

Comment: how so? isn't `await user.register(data)` the way to wait for the data to be returned? I honestly don't think adding a delay is the best option, should suffice with sync/await, I may be doing it wrong for sure but there should be a correct solution using only sync/await without the need of adding a delay

Answer (score 2):

There are some Redux rules that are being broken here:

1. **Don't do side effects in reducers**:
   reducers should be pure functions: for the same input, return always
   the same output. This is not the place to do API calls.
2. **State should be immutable**: you should never change a state value by reference, always provide a new state with a new object containing the changes.

So, the classical redux approach would be to have three actions in Redux: REGISTER_USER, REGISTER_USER_SUCCEEDED, REGISTER_USER_FAILED .

`reducer`:

```
const authReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {

        case actionTypes.REGISTER_USER:
            return {
                ...state,
                status: 'loading'
            }
        case actionTypes.REGISTER_USER_SUCCEEDED:
            return {
                ...state,
                status: 'idle',
                user: action.user 
            }
        case actionTypes.REGISTER_USER_FAILED:
            return {
                ...state,
                status: 'error'
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Then, async work should be done in your event handlers:

`onSubmit`:

```
const onSubmit = async data => {
        // ...
        dispatch(registerNewUser());
        const user = new User()
        try {
          await user.register(data);
          dispatch(registerNewUserSucceeded(user));
        } catch(e) {
          console.error(e);
          dispatch(registerNewUserFailed());
        }
    }
```

**Don't forget to return the promise from axios inside your register function, so you can await on the promise. Currently, you are only calling axios, but not updating or returning anything...

What's great about this, is that testing your store doesn't require you to do any network calls! You could ditch MSW (although it's a great lib, just not needed here).

In your tests, just check your store state before and after every transition:

```
const mockUser = {...} // provide a mock user for your test
const store = createStore(authReducer);
store.dispatch(registerNewUserSucceeded(mockUser);
expect(store.getState()).toEqual({user: mockUser, status: 'idle'});
```

---

**Edit**

In response to the asker's edit, there is now a bug because of the confusing combination of `await` with `.then`.
Specifically, in `onSubmit`, you are doing both `await` and `.then` on the same promise. In this case, there is a race condition. The `.then` call happens first, and after that the `await` happens.
So instead of `await user.register(data).then(...)`:

```
const onSubmit = async data => {
    // ...
    try {
        await user.register(data);
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
    dispatch(createNewUser(data));
}
```

Here I'm only using await. the `try`/`catch` clause is instead of calling `.catch` on the promise.
using `await` lets you write as if you are writing synchronic code, so just write whatever you would put inside `.then` on the next line after an `await` expression.

Also in your register function:

```
async register(data) {
    try {
        let res = await axios.post(...);
        return res; 
    } catch(e) {
        console.log("error: ", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @deckele! I implemented most of your suggestions and it seems to be partly working. Partly because sometimes I see the correct values in the store and some other times I see `null`, I guess I'm missing some async code somewhere, please check my updated questions (after the EDIT mark)

Comment: @MrCujo You are very close! there is a mistake where you are combining `await` and `.then` for confusing results... specifically in `onSubmit`:  `await user.register(data).then(...)` is a bug, because you are awaiting the result from after `.then`, but you actually wanted to await the `register` call first, and only after, do something with the result.

Comment: @MrCujo see my edited answer with examples

Comment: thanks. I now understand the difference between `await` and `.then`. I've made the suggested code changes yet the result seems to be the same. Sometimes I get `null` some other times I get the expected value in the store

Answer (score 0):

The state won't be updated instantly, as the server call is a promise. You should await something on the page the indicates the process is complete like this:

```js
        // Click on the Submit button
        await act(async () => {
            userEvent.click(screen.getByTestId('register-submit-button'));

            await wait(() => getByText('Some text that appears after success '));

            // verify the store was populated
            console.log(await store.getState())
        });
```

Or you can wait for the update:

```js
        // Click on the Submit button
        await act(async () => {
            userEvent.click(screen.getByTestId('register-submit-button'));
            
            await act(() => sleep(500));

            // verify the store was populated
            console.log(await store.getState())
        });
```

Comment: that's exactly what i'm doing except for this part `await wait(() => getByText('Some text that appears after success '));` since nothing should be displayed in the page, in real life it should be redirected to a different page and the store oughta be populated

Comment: I've updated the answer

Comment: that doesn't seem to be working. I added a `setTimeout` but the result is still the same. I don't think that's the reason, I believe the whole point of adding stuff within the `act` statement is that will wait for the promise to be resolved

Comment: This is correct, you should only check the store after the api call has completed. - but also Also make sure the `new User(). register ()` call returns a promise and is awaited. Currently it returns `undefined`.

Comment: @MarcRo yeah, I implemented those changes, now sometimes when I run my test I'm getting the right value from the store some other times I'm getting `null`. Please check my updated question after the EDIT mark.